# Faster build times in C++

Tags: c++, build, compilation

What should I look for or pay attention to when trying to optimize C++ application for faster build times? Smaller translation units? Less dependencies?

Does splitting large units into multiple smaller ones, where they will include each other can help or it won't change a thing?

Can someone point me in the right direction, what to look for in such a process or where to find more information about it?

Comment: I always recommend `ccache`.

Comment: Forward declaration instead of `#include` when possible

Comment: See also: https://www.codeguru.com/cplusplus/reduce-compilation-dependencies-in-large-scale-c-projects-factory-pattern/

Comment: Are you talking a rebuild (of all sources) or are you talking about only building the sources that have changed?

Comment: You may want to do a `#ifdef INCLUDE_FILE_HEADER #include "file_header.hpp" #endif`.  The point here is that you save the time of opening and reading a file.